# Trying to get property of non-object when accessing a variable from Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know there are multiple threads with this problem but they always have a different cause and none of them seem to be the same as mine.

I am trying to access a value from a Database, the conection is fine, I just have gotten this error quite a few times and I've gotten away with it by changing `fetch_object()` for `fetch_assoc()` (i don't know why that works).. But here nothing seems to work:

```
include 'structure.php';
include 'conexion.php';

$con = new conexion();
$bd = $con->conect();

$querycliente = $con->obtener('cliente');
$row = $querycliente->fetch_object();

$id_cliente = $row->id_cliente;

$p_dom = $con->obtener('presupuesto', " cliente_id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' AND servicio = 'dominio' ");
$p_host = $con->obtener('presupuesto', " cliente_id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' AND servicio = 'hosting' ");
$p_correos = $con->obtener('presupuesto', " cliente_id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' AND servicio = 'correos' ");

$precio1 = $p_dom->fetch_object();
$precio2 = $p_host->fetch_object();
$precio3 = $p_correos->fetch_object();
```

I keep getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootproject\precios.php on line 26 (and in the other lines where i try to access a value from the Databse), it only works the first time, in `$id_cliente = $row->id_cliente;` , so why don't the rest work?

This is the class and the methods I'm using (wich are working fine as i've already used them multiple times throughout the rest of my code):

```
class conexion{

    public $dbase;

    function conect(){
        $this->dbase = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx','xxxx');
    }

    function obtener($tabla, $where = ""){
        $where = ($where != "") ? 'WHERE '.$where: '';
        $query = $this->dbase->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$tabla.'` '.$where);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Hope you can help, thank you on anticipation.

Answer (score -1):

use **$result->close();** more examples into documentation [MySQLi query function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
$p_dom = $con->obtener('presupuesto', " cliente_id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' AND servicio = 'dominio' ");
$precio1 = $p_dom->fetch_object();
$p_dom->close();

$p_host = $con->obtener('presupuesto', " cliente_id_cliente = '".$id_cliente."' AND servicio = 'hosting' ");
$precio2 = $p_host->fetch_object();
$p_host->close();
```

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work, it keeps giving me the same error

Comment: Also, I tried to do "$row->close();" and it gave me this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::close() in...

Comment: That's right error *because close()* should be set for *$querycliente*, not for $row. That stuffs should works, you have error *precios.php on line 26* probably it not that code, because last line of that code near 20

Comment: Line 26 is where I tried to access the value from the database using echo $precio1->precio; ... I (sort of) figured it out now. I was getting that error because I had no records in the table I was trying to access.. Still not sure why it says "non-object" but It'll do for now... Thank you @dwaskowski

Answer (score -1):

I (sort of) figured it out now. I was getting that error because I had no records in the table I was trying to access... Still not sure why it says "non-object", here's how I solved it:

```
if($p_dom->num_rows > 0){
     echo $precio1->precio;
}
```

That way the code will check if there are any records on the table before trying to access it's values